# Querying the number of elements in a buffered core.async/chan

Tags: clojure, core.async

Having a buffered `chan`, say

```
(def c (clojure.core.async/chan 100))
```

is it possible to query how many elements are currently inside the chan?

Answer (score 6, accepted):

The instantiated channel is from `ManyToManyChannel` type, you can access the internal buffer for the channel using the `buf` property.

```
(.buf c)
 => #<FixedBuffer clojure.core.async.impl.buffers.FixedBuffer@3d67452c>
```

That buffer implements `clojure.lang.Counted` so it's countable.

```
(count (.buf c))
=> 0
```